# Align bottom of node with horizontal line

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams, nodes, tikz-arrows

I'm using tikz to draw a few simple nodes. I need to draw a horizontal line between two nodes that is aligned with the bottom edge of the nodes. With my current solution, the line and the bottom edge are offset by what looks like the width of the line.

[image]

Zoomed in:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (client) [draw, rectangle] {Client};
    \node (server) [draw, rectangle, right=of client] {Server};
    \draw (client.south east) -- (server.south west);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Fastest solution may be: `\draw ([yshift=.5\pgflinewidth]client.south east) -- ([yshift=.5\pgflinewidth]server.south west);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to remove the small separation surrounding the nodes by using `outer sep=0mm`. With

```
\documentclass[border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (client) [draw, rectangle, outer sep=0cm] {Client};
    \node (server) [draw, rectangle, outer sep=0cm, right=of client] {Server};
    \draw (client.south east) -- (server.south west);
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

you get the output
[image]